# Can't install via usb stick

Tags: unity, system-installation

I'm installing the latest version but it says that files is unable to copy on harddisk due to usb is burned too fast it gives this error in between of the installation I can try it but can't install it.

Please help

Comment: Check the md5sum of the downloaded iso and also try to make a bootable usb drive through unetbootin.

Comment: Do it again. It works or it doesn't. Burning is for cds not usb. You need not just the iso image but to make the usb bootable.

Comment: i tried with 3 different usb stick but still gives the same error. I tried to do it with the official application given in the installation process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and install 'unetbootin' software in your system, [click here](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to download.

Select radio button -> Disk Image and select 'iso' file, select usb ddrive you want.

Click 'OK'. Wit till finish. Restart system, if not boot with ubuntu. Enter setup and make usb into first for booting by pressing F6. And save and exit(F10) now you will got Ubuntu Desktop. Select Install Ubuntu to install Ubuntu. And restart system before boot start remove usb drive.

Answer (score 0):

With these kind of problems "usb not burned correctly" usually turns out to be the problem most of the time. Try and recreate another ubuntu bootable usb stick - usually the latest version is the best even if you created the one you have a few months ago. From experience its usually the usb bootable disk when this errors happen. Goodluck.